# SSIS Package fails to execute using SQL Job while accessing shared folder cross domain

Tags: ssis, cross-domain, kerberos, sql-job

**Scenario:** Read Excel file from a shared folder on a different domain

**Issue:** SSIS Package works fine when run manually from SQL server but when I tried to run it using SQL job it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is **Kerberos Authentication configuration**  between two domains so that the SQL Server Job agent can access the shared folder from another domain.